# Custom ListView onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview

Created listView with custom adapter and row layout, but can't set onClickListener to it properlly. onClickListener was working when it was android in built list, not a custom one.. Don't know why it doesn't work now. 
Anyway, here's the code

List

```
public class VjezbeLista extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listaVjezbe;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String[] misicneSkupine = {"Prsa",
            "Leđa",
            "Ramena",
            "Biceps",
            "Triceps",
            "Trbuh",
            "Kvadriceps",
            "Loža",
            "Listovi"};

    Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_prsa,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_ledja,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_ramena,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_biceps,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_triceps,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_trbuh,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_kvadriceps,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_loza,
            R.drawable.ic_vjezbe_listovi};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vjezbe_lista);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        AdapterListaVjezbe adapter = new AdapterListaVjezbe(VjezbeLista.this, misicneSkupine, imageId);
        listaVjezbe = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaVjezbe);
        listaVjezbe.setAdapter(adapter);
        listaVjezbe.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(VjezbeLista.this, VjezbeListaPrsa.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } // Here will go else if etc...

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pretraga, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
public class AdapterListaVjezbe extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;


     public AdapterListaVjezbe(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.layout_lista_vjezbe_2, web);

        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_vjezbe_2, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textLista);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewListaVjezbe2);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btnVjezbePrsaPotisakSKlupe"
        android:minHeight="72dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="56dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewListaVjezbe2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_potisak_s_klupe" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/potisakSKlupe"
                    android:id="@+id/textLista"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.9"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageVisdfsdew19"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_strelica"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:minHeight="36dp"
                    android:minWidth="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So if anyone can walk me through my errors, I would appreciate it.. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe your item is not attach to your rootparent. Did you try View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista_vjezbe_2, parent, true); ?

Comment: it gives    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView error

Comment: The `android:clickable="true"` in the `android:id="@+id/btnVjezbePrsaPotisakSKlupe"` RelativeLayout looks suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this line after fill date in listview

listaVjezbe.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **android:clickable="true"** in the linear layout that has the id "btnVjezbePrsaPotisakSKlupe" in the row layout you specified. Because, the click event is triggered for the linear layout and not for the whole list item layout.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **android:clickable="true"** from the  btnVjezbePrsaPotisakSKlupe LineareLayout. then it will work fine (tested)

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/btnVjezbePrsaPotisakSKlupe"
        android:minHeight="72dp"

        android:clickable="true"

        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
```